# Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend, babeljs

I am following the React Scrimba course. I am just trying to get my server up and running on a basic React Page.

```
PS D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce> npm run build

> build
> webpack

asset index.pack.js 1.22 KiB [compared for emit] (name: index)
./index.js 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce\node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js
    at createDescriptor (D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:159:11)
    at createDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
    at D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 963 ms`
```

Seems like a babel dependency problem. I uninstalled and installed the latest versions and tried to map through the error message, still cant fix it.
According to the error message: at createDescriptor.next () This I cant figure out. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@babel/preset-react`

`babel-preset-react` hasn't been updated for years

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. I did that. Its getting imported. Cannot find package 'babel-preset-env' imported from D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce\babel-virtual-resolve-base.js

Comment: And, Cannot find package 'babel-preset-react' imported from D:\MY_FILES\react-scrimba\test\cz2NaGce\babel-virtual-resolve-base.js

Comment: Even tried, creating a .babelrc file with this:
 {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
    ]
}